# How can I prevent hammerspoon hotkeys from overriding hotkeys in other applications?

Tags: hammerspoon

I'm looking at having a certain hotkey only available in Google Chrome:

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd"}, "0", function()
  if hs.window.focusedWindow():application():name() == 'Google Chrome' then
    hs.eventtap.keyStrokes("000000000000000000")
  end
end)
```

The issue with this approach is the hotkey will become un-usable on other apps. E.g. `CMD`+`0` will not trigger the `Reset Zoom` command in Discord.

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`hs.hotkey`](http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.hotkey.html#new) API doesn't provide functionality to be able to propagate the captured keydown event. The [`hs.eventtap`](http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.eventtap.html#new) API does, but using it would involve watching for *every* `keyDown` event.

I'll point to what is mentioned in a somewhat related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/issues/2081#issuecomment-486572597):

> If you're wanting the key combo to do something for most applications, but not for a few specific ones, you're better off using a window filter or application watcher and enabling/disabling the hotkey(s) when the active application changes.

In other words, for what you're trying to achieve, it's recommended you use the [`hs.window.filter`](http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.window.filter.html) API to enable the hotkey binding when entering the application, and disable it when leaving the application, i.e. something like:

```lua
-- Create a new hotkey
local yourHotkey = hs.hotkey.new({ "cmd" }, "0", function()
    hs.eventtap.keyStrokes("000000000000000000")
end)

-- Initialize a Google Chrome window filter
local GoogleChromeWF = hs.window.filter.new("Google Chrome")

-- Subscribe to when your Google Chrome window is focused and unfocused
GoogleChromeWF
    :subscribe(hs.window.filter.windowFocused, function()
        -- Enable hotkey in Google Chrome
        yourHotkey:enable()
    end)
    :subscribe(hs.window.filter.windowUnfocused, function()
        -- Disable hotkey when focusing out of Google Chrome
        yourHotkey:disable()
    end)
```